# Navbar a to change color after certain scrolling

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a problem I can't seem to solve. So, what I wish to do is when scrolling to a certain distance (preferably scrolling to a specific div box); the navbar `<a>` tag should switch color (say red) after reaching its div.

Example: `<a>` tag links to `#div`. When I scroll down to this div, the specific `<a>` tag should change color.

```css
    * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

body {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}


#logo {
    display: inline;
}

#logoo {
    position: absolute;
    top: 6%;
    left: 2%;
}

.parallax-window {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 1000px;
    background: transparent;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}

h1 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 52%;
    top: 45%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 4vw;
    width: 1300px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

@media only screen and (max-width:1000px) {
  /* For mobile phones: */
  .nav1, .content, footer {
    width:50%;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width:1000px) {
    img, h1, h3 {
        font-size: 4vw;
        width: 90%;
    }
}

.content {
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
}

#div {
    margin-top: 62.5rem;
    background-color: #222;
    color: white;
    padding: 20px 20px 5px 80px;
}

h3 {
    font-size: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}

p {
    margin-top: 150px;
    width: 50%;
    text-align: justify;
}

.me {
    left: 65%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 1.5rem;
}

#me {
    border-radius: 50%;
}

#divv {
    margin-top: 87.5rem;
    background-color: #3b3a3a;
}

ul {
    position: absolute;
    list-style-type: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: transparent;
    padding: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    margin-top: 60px;
    left: 38%;
}


li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 25px;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 0 5px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#hem {
    background-color: #292929;
    position: fixed;
    top: -10rem;
    transition: top 0.3s;
    width: 100%;
    height: 7rem;
    z-index: 1;
}

#hem ul {
    margin-left: 30rem;
}

a span {
    color: white;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 300;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}



footer {
    position: absolute;
    top: 300%;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 1.25em;
    background-color: #87ceeb;
    color: white;
    font-size: .85em;
}

footer div {
    margin: auto;
    width: 70%;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 1.25em 0px;
}

.footer-icons a {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 35px;
    height: 35px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #33383b;
    border-radius: 4px;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 35px;
    margin-right: 3px;
}

#facebook:hover {
    background-color: #3b5998;
    transition: 0.25s linear;
}

#twitter:hover {
    color: #008ad8;
    background-color: white;
    transition: 0.25s linear;
}

#youtube:hover {
    color: #C31A1E;
    transition: 0.25s linear;
}

#instagram:hover {
    background: radial-gradient(circle at 33% 100%, #FED373 4%, #F15245 30%, #D92E7F 62%, #9B36B7 85%, #515ECF);
}


.left-links {
    margin-right: 10px;
}


footer .name {
    font-size: 1.2rem;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="sv">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css" />
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/parallax.js/1.4.2/parallax.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <main>
            <div class="parallax-window" data-parallax="scroll" data-image-src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/bb/e7/42/bbe742c899cb149fadfc5dba9117311b.jpg">
                <header>
                    <nav class="nav1">
                        <div id="logo">
                            <img id="logoo" src="https://git-scm.com/images/logos/downloads/Git-Logo-White.png" height="100" width="239" />
                        </div>
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#hem">
                                    <span>hem</span>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">
                                    <span>om mig</span>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">
                                    <span>mitt arbete</span>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                    <nav class="nav2" id="hem">
                        <div class="logo" id="logo">
                            <img id="logoo" src="https://git-scm.com/images/logos/downloads/Git-Logo-White.png" height="100" width="239" />
                        </div>
                        <ul class="ul1">
                            <li>
                                <a href="#hem">
                                    <span>hem</span>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">
                                    <span>om mig</span>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">
                                    <span>mitt arbete</span>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                </header>
            </div>
                <h1>Välkommen till min hemsida!</h1>
                <div id="div" class="content">
                    <h3>Om mig</h3>
                    <p>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
                    </p>
                    <div class="me">
                        <img id="me" src="me.jpg" width="263" height="350">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="divv" class="content">

                </div>
        </main>
        <footer>
            <div>
                Have a question? Email us at
                <a href="mailto:example@example.com">travel@dandeliontours.com</a>
            </div>
            <div class="footer-icons">
                <a id="facebook" href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
                <a id="twitter" href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
                <a id="instagram" href="#"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a>
                <a id="youtube" href="#"><i class="fa fa-youtube"></i></a>
            </div>
            <div>
                You'll travel with the wind. <span class="name">Dandelion Tours</span>.
            </div>
        </footer>
        <script>
            window.onscroll = function() {scrollFunction()};

            function scrollFunction() {
                if (document.body.scrollTop > 130 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 130) {
                    document.getElementById("hem").style.top = "0";
                } else {
                    document.getElementById("hem").style.top = "-10rem";
                }
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

P.S: The linked js file is parallax effect scrolling.

Appreciate the help!

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/xvg26a0e/

Comment: https://codepen.io/latifur/pen/qLKXpj check this if help

Answer (score 0):

i know this is not the optimal solution for this problem. and it will be a lot of code if you have a lot of links but just to give you a solution.

The idea is to get the offset of the divs that triggers your style changing. and listen to your window onscroll event. Whenever you reached the beginning of the div you add a class pre defined, and deleting it whenever you leave the div

in your case :

html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css" />
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/parallax.js/1.4.2/parallax.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <main class="parallax-window" data-parallax="scroll" data-image-src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/bb/e7/42/bbe742c899cb149fadfc5dba9117311b.jpg">
            <header>
                <nav class="nav1">
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a id="link1">
                                <span>hem</span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a id="link2">
                                <span>om mig</span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a>
                                <span>mitt arbete</span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </header>
            <div id="div"></div>
            <div id="divv"></div>
        </main>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
.newClass>span{
  color: red;
}
```

js :

```
let div = document.getElementById("div");
let divv = document.getElementById("divv");

let link1 = document.getElementById("link1");
let link2 = document.getElementById("link2");

//getting offset
let divOffset = div.offsetTop;
let divvOffset = divv.offsetTop;

//setting the class when it enters the range 
window.onscroll = ()=>{
if (window.pageYOffset >= divOffset && window.pageYOffset <= divvOffset) {
    link1.classList.add("newClass")
  } else {
    link1.classList.remove("newClass");
  }
 if (window.pageYOffset >= divvOffset) {
    link2.classList.add("newClass")
  } else {
    link2.classList.remove("newClass");
  }
}
```

**ps: this is not the perfect solution, you can use JQuery to get this done easelly. you can check this link to use that https://codepen.io/latifur/pen/qLKXpj.**

Hope that it was helpful

Comment: Hmm, the link you sent is exactly what I need. But problem is, I can't seem to get it working for me, and I also wonder if I can change color of the span element when reaching the specific divs. Look at my updated Jsfiddle to understand better :)

Comment: if the code in the link didn't work, try using the code i gave you, it should work, i tryed it in your project in the link you gave in the question.

Comment: Very well, but I do have more links (a tags). Should I add additional links (link 3, link 4 etc)?

Comment: well that will be a long code but you can play around with this code, like adding elements in an array and do the condition based on the current element offset.

Comment: Well the code does work, but when I try to add additional links and such my navbar just seems to dissapear for no apparent reason. It only works with the way you set up the code; I can't get it to work any other way...